# Access a custom class from a new thread in a ProgressDialog on Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have created a ProgressDialog in android and it works when I do a simple example.

For example, this works.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // Perform action on click
    System.out.println("Progess Bar");
    final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidTestApplicationActivity.this,
                    "Please wait...", "Getting updates...", true);

    new Thread() 
    {
            public void run() 
            {
                    try
                    {
                            // Do some Fake-Work
                            sleep(5000);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    { 

                    }

                    // Dismiss the Dialog
                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
    }.start();

}
```

But once I add in a reference to my custom class, it just stops running this new thread.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Perform action on click
        System.out.println("Progess Bar");
        // Display an indeterminate Progress-Dialog
        final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidTestApplicationActivity.this,
                        "Please wait...", "Getting Updates...", true);

        new Thread() 
        {
                public void run() 
                {
                        try
                        {
                                HealthySubObject hsObject = new HealthySubObject();
                                // Do some more work with my hsObject - nothing happens after this point. 
                                sleep(5000);
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        { 

                        }

                        // Dismiss the Dialog
                        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
        }.start();

    }
});
```

What happens is that as soon as I click this button, the progress dialog flashes up on the screen real quick and then disappears.  But if you look at my code, it should wait 5 seconds before disappearing.  I have put debug statements before and after the reference to my custom class and I can see the statements before but not the ones after.  Does anyone have any idea why that is happening?  As long as my class is public I should be able to call it from a new thread, right?

I am still pretty new to android and this is my first adventure into multi-threaded android apps.  Any help would be much appreciated.

***SOLUTION***

Thanks for your help everyone.  It is working now.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Perform action on click
            System.out.println("Progess Bar");
            //ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidTestApplicationActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            // Display an indeterminate Progress-Dialog
            final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidTestApplicationActivity.this,
                            "Please wait...", "Doing Extreme Calculations...", true);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    HealthySubObject hsObject = new HealthySubObject();
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> onlineDB = hsObject.jsonToArray(); 
                    //
                    // more stuff goes here.  
                    //
                    //
                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 1500);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend to use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead of Thread. Using the `Thread.sleep` method is actually discouraged. Something like this is much better:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HealthySubObject hsObject = new HealthySubObject();
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to be on the UI thread to do modify the UI, and inside the run() method of your Thread you are in a "background" thread. Try using a handler inside your thread when you need to access the UI thread.